# ldapadd/modify a single entry

Tags: shell, ldap, ldif

I want to add a new entry to my LDAP server without using an .ldif file. the reasons for this is I am connecting to the server remotely and the file wont be present. The command to add entries from a file is:

```
$ ldapmodify -h hostName -p 10389 -D "uid=admin,ou=system" -w ****** -a -f e.ldif
```

how can I change the above to add this user without using .ldif file:

```
dn: cn=Person Name 7,dc=example,dc=com
objectclass: top
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
cn: Person Name 7
sn: Person 7
description: Sir Thomas Masterman Hardy
givenname: Person
homePhone: 11119211
mail: person7@royal.co.uk
telephoneNumber: 11111
uid: person7
```

I have looked online but all the examples seem to show file only. Is this possible?

Comment: which shell are you using?

Comment: i might have my terminology wrong, i want to execute this on the terminal in redhat. does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the `man` page, the default behavior of `ldapmodify` is actually *not* to use a file but rather to take its information from `stdin` -- i.e. from someone typing it in.  By using `-f` on the command line you're actually circumventing that normal behavior.  Try doing:

```
ldapmodify -h hostName -p 10389 -D "uid=admin,ou=system" -w ***** -a
```

and then paste or type in the information.  (You may have to type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> when you're done typing in the information in order to tell `ldapmodify` that you're done.)

Comment: So how would i add the entry in the question using this method? just copy it in at the end of the command?

Comment: Type the command.  Hit Enter.  Once the program connects, it should sit there waiting for input.  (It may even print a message telling you what to do.)  Then paste the contents of the file.